# PyParsing "parseString" class unavailable

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, pyparsing

I am trying to build a quick script that extracts only certain information from invoice PDFs without using regex.
When I try to define the grammar for, say, electric usage, I get an error "cannot import name 'parseString' from 'pyparsing'"
I have tried reinstalling, modifying casing from camel to snake, etc etc but I am at a loss at this point.
Here is the (I think) relevant documentation:
https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyparsing.html

The code:

```
electric_usage = pp.Word(nums) + ',' + pp.Word(nums) + 'kwh'

dates_1 = pp.Word(nums) + '-' + pp.Word(nums) + '-' + pp.Word(nums)

dates_2 = pp.Word(nums) + '/' + pp.Word(nums) + '/' + pp.Word(nums)



for str in pdf_text:
    usage_pulled = electric_usage.parseString(pdf_text)
    print(usage_pulled)
```

here is an example of one of the regex patterns that actually seems to work to pull usage values:

'[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[,]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]'

and cost:
'[$]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[,]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[.]+[0-9]+[0-9]+$'

Comment: All this code requires is `import pyparsing as pp`.  There is no need to import parseString separately - it is an instance method of the `electric_usage` variable (which is of type pp.And, created in the first line of your code). You may also want searchString instead of parseString, if you trying to extract that fragment from a larger text file.

Comment: @PaulMcG thank you, but it looks like even if I amend the notation to accord with that, it now thinks that "nums" is not defined, but within the PyParsing docs it seems perfectly valid to pass in as an argument to, for example, the Word class. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes - `nums` is a name defined in pyparsing, so in your code, you have to refer to it as `pp.nums` (just like you did for `pp.Word`).

Comment: @PaulMcG so I'm getting what seems to be a type error that I thought I had dealt with by casting the string (resulting from the pdf parser) to a list. 'pdf_text = list(pdf_text)
for i in pdf_text:
    usage_pulled = electric_usage.searchString(pdf_text)
    print(usage_pulled)'

Comment: You will need to troubleshoot this yourself, I am not familiar with your PDF text extractor. But do not just make random changes hoping something will click (like adding a "cast" - if pdf_text is a str, list(pdf_cast) will give you a list of single characters, likely not what you want) . Use a debugger or more print() statements and make changes that make sense.  Test the parts of your program separately. Call electric_usage.searchString on an actual string with meaningful data to verify it works correctly. Verify what you get from the PDF to be a valid input string. _Then_ put them together.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to avoid arbitrary casting and data type manipulation.....